# ANDROID GRADLE SYNC

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Anyone here knows how to fix this error? I'm trying to sync project with gradle files. Thanks in advance!

> Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown
>   property 'KEY_ALIAS' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias project.KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword project.KEY_PASSWORD
            storeFile file(project.STORE_FILE)
            storePassword project.STORE_PASSWORD
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368594/groovy-lang-missingpropertyexception-could-not-get-unknown-property-manifestou

Comment: Look for `KEY_ALIAS` in your Gradle files and show us.

Comment: Here's what i can find. (Btw this is just a source code i found on gitHub, im new to android studio and trying to experiments on some finished written codes.)                                 
                                                                                                                         
      android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias project.KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword project.KEY_PASSWORD
            storeFile file(project.STORE_FILE)
            storePassword project.STORE_PASSWORD
        }
    }